# Django. get() returned more than one Card. Ошибка в get_object_or_404

Tags: django

Подскажите как исправить код.
Хочу чтобы карты с одинаковой `strength` выводились в шаблоне. Когда использую `ability = Card.objects.filter(strength=abilityes)` выводится всё как нужно. Но когда хочу использовать `get_object_or_404` ругается что `get` возвращает больше чем одну карту.
Как закомментированую строку переписать с помощью метода `get_object_or_404`, чтобы выводились все карты с одинаковой `strength` и без ошибки?

```
class Abilities(View):
    def get(self, request, abilityes):
        #ability = Card.objects.filter(strength__iexact=abilityes)
        ability = get_object_or_404(Card, strength = abilityes)
        return render(request, 'Board/abilities.html', context={'ability': ability})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак

```
ability = Card.objects.filter(strength__iexact=abilityes)
if not ability:
    raise Http404
```